# g++ fail to build with boost locale precompiled headers on windows 7

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using **mingw-w64** on **windows 7**, i've successfuly compiled **boost 1.60**, and it works fine when it's about inline headers, unfortunately when i do the following command to build a simple testing app:

```
g++ -W -Wall -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test.exe -L"C:\boost_1_60_0\stage\lib" -I"C:\boost_1_60_0" -lboost_locale-mgw48-mt-d-1_60 -lboost_system-mgw48-mt-d-1_60
```

the compilation fail with the error:

```
C:\boost_1_60_0\stage\lib/libboost_locale-mgw48-mt-d-1_60.a(codepage.o): In function `boost::locale::call_iconv(void*, char**, unsigned long long*, char**, unsigned long long*)':
C:\boost_1_60_0/libs/locale/src/encoding/../util/iconv.hpp:50: undefined reference to `iconv'
C:\boost_1_60_0\stage\lib/libboost_locale-mgw48-mt-d-1_60.a(codepage.o): In function `boost::locale::conv::impl::iconverter_base::open(char const*, char const*, boost::locale::conv::method_type)':
C:\boost_1_60_0/libs/locale/src/encoding/iconv_codepage.ipp:46: undefined reference to `iconv_open'
C:\boost_1_60_0\stage\lib/libboost_locale-mgw48-mt-d-1_60.a(codepage.o): In function `boost::locale::conv::impl::iconverter_base::close()':
C:\boost_1_60_0/libs/locale/src/encoding/iconv_codepage.ipp:132: undefined reference to `iconv_close'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using the following code:

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::locale;

int main()
{
    generator gene;
    std::locale myLocale = gene("en_US.UTF-8");

    std::cout << "name: " << std::use_facet<info>(myLocale).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "language: " << std::use_facet<info>(myLocale).language() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "country: " << std::use_facet<info>(myLocale).country() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "variant: " << std::use_facet<info>(myLocale).variant() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "encoding: " << std::use_facet<info>(myLocale).encoding() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -lboost_locale-mgw48-mt-d-1_6  Why are you linking with the debug library?

Comment: I've tried with both debug and not debug library, the problem remain, but with the debug one the error messages is a little more readable.

Comment: Don't you need to link to iconv as well?

Comment: well, i've installed cygwin, few dependency, and added -liconv, and now its working fine.